# Probability of two cities not reachable to each other [Application]

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This problem was presented to us in class today as a "riddle" tricky problem, and our teacher requested that we complete this problem as Homework:

Cities A,B, ... , Z are connected in a loop by 26 two-way roads: A to B, B to C, ... , Y to Z, and Z to A. Each road can be destroyed by rain with probability p independently of the others.

a.) Find the probability that, after the rain, there are two cities that are not reachable from each other.

b.) Find the probability that, after the rain, it is possible to get from A to Z.

(I don't know how to approach this problem at all. It would be greatly appreciated if someone can help solve this, but most importantly, explain the steps of how they got it; thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for part (a) consider what happens when one road is broken.  Does it leave two cities that aren't connected to each other?  What about if two are broken?

For part (b), how many ways are there to get from A to Z?  What are the probabilities that these paths are broken?

Comment: Based on that thinking, I got that the probability would be 26b^2 and for (b) I got 1-b. Can anyone verify if that is correct?

Comment: @JoeDaly, That's not correct.  For part (a), you have the right idea, but it's not exactly there just yet.  The probability that at least 2 or broken try computing the probability that exactly 0 or 1 are broken and relating it to the probability of at least 2.  For (b), you're close; you can get from A to Z either the short way or the long way.  What's the probability that *both* ways are obstructed?